# Background of a scroll pane

Tags: javafx

I have a scroll pane with style: -fx-background-color.
The scroll pane contents an anchorpane (with style: -fx-background-color). This one has children (VBox ... )
If I expand the window, there are white parts (withouth background).
How can I fix it?

Comment: You might wish to enhance your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that somebody can reproduce your described issue.

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollPane is not technically a "Pane".  You need to use the inner control to access it.

```
.scrollpane-transparent {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-control-inner-background: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 0;
}
```

Then add this to your scroll pane.

Comment: Did you add the style to your scroll pane?  this is what I am doing so that the scroll pane has no color.

Comment: Yes and I have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Check these lines of css code:

```
   //Makes the viewport transparent
   .scroll-pane .viewport {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
  }

  .scroll-pane {
    -fx-background-color:transparent;
  }


  .scroll-bar{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
  }
```